# regex match in findall not working consistently

Tags: python, regex

Can anyone tell me why the regex pattern in Python works most of the time but have difficulty with the following text.

PATTERN:

```
patternd = re.compile(r"""\(VFSCAN\)[^=]*=\s*    # first line of a section: (VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP    TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200 
(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)                 # group 1 - first number of first line: 1.1800
\D+ 
\d+                             # second number of first line: 100 
\s+BUSES\s+WITH\s+LOW\s+VOLTAGE\s+(DEVIATION)\s+BELOW.*? 
\D+                             # skip second line 
(?:                             # a data line: 18436 [LENZIE 618.0] -0.245 18433 [LENZIE 318.0] -0.245
(?:\d+\s+\[(.+?)\]\s+\S+\s*)+   # Component of data line
(?=[\r\n\s]+|$) 
)+                              # This search ends with an empty line
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

The text I am having problems with is:

```
test3 = r'''(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV       X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV
18436 [LENZIE 618.0]   -0.245      18433 [LENZIE 318.0]   -0.245     
18431 [LENZIE 118.0]   -0.214      18435 [LENZIE 518.0]   -0.214     
18434 [LENZIE 418.0]   -0.214      18432 [LENZIE 218.0]   -0.214     

(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.5167 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV       X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV
69036 [DNLP2G21.575]   -0.414      69038 [DNLP2G22.575]   -0.414     
69040 [DNLP2G23.575]   -0.414      69032 [DNLP1_G1.575]   -0.402     
65460 [DIFICULT 230]   -0.384      69027 [7MIHL G1.575]   -0.355     
69076 [HORIZ_G .575]   -0.303      67237 [MEDBOWCO 115]   -0.301     
67940 [STNDPSVC 230]   -0.300      65976 [MINERS  34.5]   -0.294     
65585 [FT CRK1 34.5]   -0.261      65584 [FT CRK2 34.5]   -0.261     
69073 [HIPLN_G .575]   -0.214     

(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV       X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV
65191 [BONANZA 24.0]   -0.572      65192 [BONANZA  138]   -0.434     
65194 [CHAPITA  138]   -0.433      66278 [RANGELY  138]   -0.320     
65371 [COVE TP  138]   -0.302      79265 [CALAMRDG 138]   -0.286     
79400 [DES.MINE 138]   -0.285      65086 [ASHLEY  69.0]   -0.284     
79067 [VERNAL   138]   -0.277      67257 [MOONLAK269.0]   -0.268     
67256 [MOONLAK169.0]   -0.266      79264 [W.RV.CTY 138]   -0.206     

'''
```

I am using  "findall" to match the text using the pattern above and expect to extract a list of tuples. When I run this I am getting:

```
[('1.1800', 'DEVIATION', 'LENZIE 218.0'), ('1.5167', 'DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575'),     ('1.1800', 'DEVIATION', 'W.RV.CTY 138')]
```

But I should be getting a lot more matched tuples in my list. I am really only interested in extracting the time on the first line of each match along with all the items in the square brackets "[]". I should be getting 6+13+12 = 31 tuples in the list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like something you want to parse with something else; regular expressions won't parse the arbitrary number of lines following each header, only the *first* matching line will be included.

Comment: That's not strictly true (depending on how you craft your regex), but the advice is sound :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want cannot be done using regular expressions. (At least, not in a single regular expression). The number of subgroups inside a group or a match cannot be variable. Compare this simplified version of your regular expression.

```
p = re.compile('(a(b)+)')
test3 = 'ababbabbbabbbb'
print p.findall(test3)
```

You want it to return something like this:

```
[('ab', 'b'), ('abb', 'b', 'b'), ('abbb', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('abbbb', 'b')]
```

Instead it returns this:

```
[('ab', 'b'), ('abb', 'b'), ('abbb', 'b'), ('abbbb', 'b')]
```

Based on the example data, you could use a two pass algorithm. You could first use your original regular expression (without the grouping that makes it fail) to extract the big blocks of text. Then, using a second regular expression, you can extract the subpatterns from the blocks you found in the first pass.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This was where I started but was convinced that a regular expression would do the job. The pattern I have works for most of the data I have without a problem. To clarify, these sections are dispersed throughout my files. I want to match the entire section and group the time from the first line and all the data in the []s. Currently the group is returning only the last [] in each match. If I remove the grouping I get what I expect, a list of text for each (VFSCAN) section. Adding the group causes it to fail somehow.

Comment: Ah now I understand what you are trying to do. I have adapted my original answer.

Comment: Hans, that sounds reasonable, I will try to do that. The regex works perfectly when I remove the grouping so I will try the two stage process. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might consider accepting the answer. This will provide feedback to other users that this is a helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to parse this format line by line, a regular expression won't go back in the text once a match has been found. You expect the regular expression to find overlapping sections (line 0 + line 2, then line 0 + line 3, etc.), but the engine has already matched something at lines 0 - 2, so the *next* match `findall` will search for starts after line 2.

Split the input by lines, detect the header lines and data lines, and parse each accordingly. Then group data lines with the most recently parsed header.

Comment: I started out going line by line but the pattern I am using works for most of the cases (I think... I will check again). If Iremove the grouping parens findall returns a list of strings corresponding with all the matches. I am willing to do whatever will work. I thought I was so close with this regex.

Comment: @user1642486: Don't look at regular expressions as a hammer in search of nails. :-) If a saw works better, use that!